# Build type version in git repository

Tags: android, git, branch, version

Hi i'm new in git and started using it for my project.

I have android project and in somehow i want to create multiple version for my project and that's will be multiple package name such

com.xxx.x1 -> build for company 1

com.xxx.x2 -> build for company 2

com.xxx.x3 -> build for company 3

For now i have multiple project for each company and if i have update in 1 version i must updated another version too.I want to centralize my code in 1 source.

So im not sure how to do this in git. should i create a branch and change package name for each or using tags version or there's better option ?

Answer (score 0):

You have a base branch like **Develop**

Then you have separate branches for all versions. You update you code in develop and then when applicable pull the changes to the individual branches from develop.

Version specific code stays in the version branch. General code can go into develop

Comment: try this, but it's success for same package name, when i edited package name in branch and try to pull from Develop Branch its become conflict

Comment: Well git is not magic. If you change text in the same are then there will be conflicts. For stuff like that it seems you are better off with a deploy script that replaces all the company specific package names after the fact